# How to query in mongoose/nodejs using Document Object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In my NodeJS code, I'm using mongoose to handle the DB calls. 
In my code I've below lines of code that will first update the "NewsReport" record, and based on the response document, I've to update "News" record based to newsId of the document. Here's my code:

```
NewsReport.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.reportId }, { $set: { 'status': statusReceived } })
    .then(result => {
        News.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: result.newsId }, { $set: { 'blocked': true } })
            .then(updatedNews => {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Successfully updated report'
                });
            });
    } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Successfully updated report'
            });
        }
    })
```

My NewsReport schema is as below (the document that will be returned after first update call:

```
var newsReportSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    newsId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'News', required: true },
    creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    type: { type: String, enum: Constants.reportTypes, required: true },
    status: { type: String, enum: Constants.reportStatus, default: 'None' }
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('NewsReport', newsReportSchema);
```

Its failing because "result.newsId" returns an Object. How can I use "findAndUpdate" based on the document object?

Comment: Hi Satyam,
follow a link:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-depopulate

Comment: @MaiconSantana, can you modify my code with depopulate functionality please and show me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
NewsReport.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.reportId }, { $set: { 'status': statusReceived } })
.then(result => {
    result.depopulate('newsId');
    News.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: result.newsId }, { $set: { 'blocked': true } })
        .then(updatedNews => {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Successfully updated report'
            });
        });
} else {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: 'Successfully updated report'
        });
    }
})
```